# How to pass arguments to systemd-nspawn via systemctl?

Tags: systemd, systemctl

I am testing `systemd-nspawn` and launch a base system `testcont` (previously created with `debootstrap`) either via

```
# systemd-nspawn -bD testcont --network-bridge=br1
```

or

```
# systemctl start systemd-nspawn@testcont.service
```

In the first case I can pass some arguments to `systemd-nspawn` (notably the bridge I want to use) - **how can I do that in the second case?**

For services I create myself I have the relevant `/etc/systemd/systemd/<something>.service` file I can adapt but in the case above the service is somehow magically started though `systemd-nspawn@` and there is no configuration file I could find.

Answer (score 0):

The `systemd-nspawn@testcont.service` is an instance from `/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-nspawn@.service`

if you want to customise, you can

```
cp /usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-nspawn@.service /etc/systemd/system/
sed -i.bak s/--network-veth/--network-bridge=br1/g /etc/systemd/system/systemd-nspawn@.service
```

then all new

```
systemctl start systemd-nspawn@testcont.service
```

will be started with `--network-bridge=br1`

if you don't want `--network-bridge=br1` by default, one could create a specific `systemd-nspawn-br1`, again :

```
cp /usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-nspawn@.service /etc/systemd/system/systemd-nspawn-br1@.service
sed -i.bak s/--network-veth/--network-bridge=br1/g /etc/systemd/system/systemd-nspawn-br1@.service
```

start with: `systemctl start systemd-nspawn-br1@testcont.service`